# Convert QueryString to Json using JAVA

Tags: java, json, jersey, jettison, flexjson

I want to convert `"id=1&location=india"` querystring to `{"id":"1","location":"india"}` json format using java.

I am using spring version 4.0.3.

Comment: show us what you've done and where did you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a direct way, but this is the first though came to my mind.
Convert the queryString to Hashtable using HttpUtils , then marshall it into JSON.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpUtils.html

Update:
HttpUtils produces Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a converter like this

```
public class ConvertToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "id=1&location=india";
        System.out.println(convert(a));
    }

    private static String convert(String a) {
        String res = "{\"";

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (a.charAt(i) == '=') {
                res += "\"" + ":" + "\"";
            } else if (a.charAt(i) == '&') {
                res += "\"" + "," + "\"";
            } else {
                res += a.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        res += "\"" + "}";
        return res;
    }
}
```

it can do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 try
    {
        String query="id=1&location=india";
        String queryArray[]=query.split("&");
        String id[]=queryArray[0].split("=");
        String location[]=queryArray[1].split("=");

        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(id[0],id[1]);
        jsonObject.put(location[0],location[1]);

        Log.i("Stackoverflow",jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Stackoverflow",e.getMessage());
    }
```